# Pause 3 seconds between array elements in dialogflow cx using $sys.func

Tags: dialogflow-cx

In dialogflow cx, I have a $session.params.perks in perks I have 9 elements which come from backend. Now for customer bot need to utter the voice saying "here are the perks we offer $session.params.perks" But the problem is for each perk I need add give 3 seconds time space.

I used

$sys.func.join(
'  '$session.params.perks, '  ') which is giving space in test agent of dialogflow cx but when placing a test call I cannot here any space between them

I even tried $sys.func.join($session.params.perks, '  ') this also didn't worked  used break time

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SSML](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml) and `break`s within Dialogflow CX to insert pauses in between the list elements within your fulfillment response.

For example, in your fulfillment response, you could use the following syntax:

```
<speak>
Your benefits include: $sys.func.JOIN(" <break time='3000ms'/>, ",
                                      $session.params.perks,
                                      " <break time='3000ms'/>, and ")
</speak>
```

which would result in the voice agent pausing for 3 seconds between each element in the list, as in "Your benefits include Benefit A [3 second pause], Benefit B [3 second pause], and Benefit C."

Relevant Documentation:

- [SSML Reference Documentation - break](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#break)
- [System Functions Documentation - JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/system-functions#func-join)